# RuntimeException: Exception inflating kotlin:navigation/nav_graph

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, parcelable, sealed-class

We had a RuntimeException while we put a safeArgs into the navigation graph and this crash didn't give us any more guide to fix it.
In the first impression, we were following this to ensure that those classes were Parcelize or not.

Therefore, those classes were parceled correctly and everything seems right.

Comment: if you're asking a question and providing an answer, then you should do exactly that - write it as a question with a problem, then write an actual answer for it (you'll see it as an option when you make the question) otherwise, it just seems like you're asking a question still

Answer (score 0):

After many searches and investigations into our codes, I found that SafeArgs class exists in a **sealed-class file**.

Considering to this point that we can't allocate the parceled annotation to the sealed classes, we've decided to move our class outside of that sealed .kt file.

Although, I found the main reason for that runtime crash was this cause.

Also, I've provided the wrong and correct cases below, We hope this will be helpful to others:

We've moved the UserFavorite and its subclass, outside of the Response.kt file,

```
sealed class Response {
.
.
 
    @Parcelize
        data class UserFavorite(
            @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
            @SerializedName("itemType") val itemType: String,
            @SerializedName("emptyIcon") val emptyIcon: String,
            @SerializedName("_texts") val texts: UserFavoriteTexts
        ) : Response(), Parcelable
  

    @Parcelize
    data class UserFavoriteTexts(
        @SerializedName("hintMessage") val hintMessage: String,
        @SerializedName("add") val add: String,
        @SerializedName("remove") val remove: String,
        @SerializedName("edit") val edit: String
        ): Parcelable

.
.
}
```

into an independent file for that: UserFavorite.kt

```
@Parcelize
    data class UserFavorite(
        @SerializedName("title") val title: String,
        @SerializedName("itemType") val itemType: String,
        @SerializedName("emptyIcon") val emptyIcon: String,
        @SerializedName("_texts") val texts: UserFavoriteTexts
    ) : Response(), Parcelable
  

@Parcelize
data class UserFavoriteTexts(
    @SerializedName("hintMessage") val hintMessage: String,
    @SerializedName("add") val add: String,
    @SerializedName("remove") val remove: String,
    @SerializedName("edit") val edit: String
    ): Parcelable
```

and, Respons.kt

```
sealed class Response {
.
.
 
.
.
}
```